# Relation between CPU cycle and Addressing modes

Tags: computer-architecture

Professor has given this question in exam. I am not able to find relevant reference for this question

Which Addressing Modes (for x86 architecture) consumes more CPU cycle?(Consider all are special purpose registers)
A. Indexed
B. PC-Relative
C. Indexed Register with displacement
D. None of the above

What I have understood is that Instruction fetch(1 cycle) and updating PC value is common for all the modes.
Indexed Mode takes 1 cycle( Effective address calculation, since base address is already decided) and 1 cycle for write to Memory.

PC- Relative will 1 cycle for Instruction decide, 1 cycle for Operand fetch from Memory and 1 cycle for Memory writeback.

Indexed register with displacement will take 1 cycle each for decode of n Instruction, 1 cycle for effective address calculation and 1 cycle for Operand fetch and 1 cycle for Memory writeback.
I am getting Indexed register with displacement mode as having more CPU cycle.

Correct me if I am wrong. Also provide reference for understanding link between CPU cycle and Addressing modes